# How to migrate images stored into S3 after changing the storage directory with the ARC library (Elixir)

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir, phoenix-framework

I’m using the arc / arc_ecto library to store medias on S3.

Recently I had to change the storing directory.
So I changed the function “storage_dir” to suit my new path to S3 like so:

```
def storage_dir(_version, {_file, %Media{} = scope}) do
  "/models/medias/#{scope.id}/"
end
```

And now that is done, all newly created medias are stored in the new directory and I can retrieve them correctly but it is impossible to retrieve medias stored in the old directory. The arc library generate an url that use the new storage directory and I can’t retrieve medias from the old one.

Does anyone know what can I do to migrate my medias from the old directory to the new one?
Is it possible to do it using Arc ecto or should I use another library related to S3?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is via the online [S3 Management Console](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/). You can select files, choose 'Cut' or 'Copy' from the 'Actions' menu, navigate to the destination folder and 'Paste'.

Comment: Each media has its own destination folder because each destination folder contains the media id (retrieve in database). Plus I don't have only one media to move so I would need to do it programmatically. Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://hexdocs.pm/ex_aws_s3/ExAws.S3.html to copy the individual objects.

If you copy the files to the new location as Arc expects them it should just work. However, I would suggest not to rely on Arc for the object keys and just store the keys in a database. This will make any future change with the object location much easier.